# Find the number of solutions of $x²=a$ in $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$ with $a \in \mathbb{Z_{11}} $

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

It is clear that there is $ 2² \equiv 4 \mod 11 $ and $ 3² \equiv 9 \mod 11 $

But we have also for example: $7² = 49 \equiv 5 \mod 11$ ?

Every number from $ \mathbb{Z_{11}}$ is equivalent to some other number in $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$

Does it admit one solution for each number $a \in \mathbb{Z_{11}} $?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z_{11}$ is a *field*, and therefore each element can have *at most* two square roots.

Furthermore, if $x^2=a$, then $(-x)^2=a$ too, and $x\ne -x$ unless $x=0$.

This means that *exactly half* of the ten nonzero elements in $\mathbb Z_{11}$ are squares; you can find them as
$$ 1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2 \pmod{11} $$

Comment: Why half of ten zeros? Other than 0, there are 10 numbers in $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$? Is the number of solutions of of the equation is 2? Thank you.

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, and each of them that _is_ a square is the square of two _different_ elements, so once you have found 5 squares, you've run out of square roots.

Comment: The number of solutions to $x^2=a$ therefore depends on what $a$ is: There are two solutions for $a=1$, no solution for $a=2$, one solution for $a=0$ ...

Comment: No solutions for $ x²=3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 $ and 2 solutions for each of $x²=1, 4, 9$ and one solution for $x²=0$. Am I correct? Thank you.